NojeJS install error (updated 10.8.1 to 10.8.2), npm function not working on Powershell anymore. Any corrections please?
Installed nojejs script on window laptop-> used update frm 10.8.1 to 10.8.2, now npm function does not work. How do I reverse or resolve error?

Ran install script from nodejs site on my windows power shell
Saw notice to update version to 10.8.2 (from 10.8.1)
When I run npm command; Powershell says scripts have been disabled

***Error Msg:
npm : File C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Local\fnm_multishells\25604_1723011425350\npm.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

npm -v # should print `10.8.1

  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess ***




I tried to run npm command, I expected it to run.
It resulted in error message below.
Error msg:
npm : File C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Local\fnm_multishells\25604_1723011425350\npm.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

npm -v # should print `10.8.1

  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess



